# What does "Clone works only for going from &T to T" mean in Rust documentation?

Tags: rust

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html

What does this mean?

> But Clone works only for going from &T to T.

Could you please explain and give an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Clone` is the way to go from a shared reference to owned version. Consider e.g. `Rc`. `<Rc as Clone>::clone()` takes `&Rc` and produces `Rc`.

Now suppose you want to impl `Clone` for `str`. The `clone()` method will need to take `&str` and return `str`. But you *cannot* return `str`, since it's unsized - the compiler cannot know how much memory to save.

Instead, it needs to return `String` which is the owned version of `str`. But it cannot with `Clone`, since `Clone` hardcodes the return type to be equal to the input type.

This is the gap `ToOwned` fills. It provides a way to go from shared to owned versions, for things where the shared and owned versions are not of the same type.

`ToOwned` is thus a superset of `Clone` (indeed, every type that impls `Clone` also impls `ToOwned` by [this blanket implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html#impl-ToOwned-5)).